# How do I add a dark tint when pressing on a tableview cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview with multiple cells. Each one contains an image and a label in the center. When a user presses on a cell, I want it to become slightly darker so the user knows that they are pressing on the cell.

Comment: UITableViewCell has an effect like this by default. Is it not what you want?

Comment: I can't see the default for some reason. I feel that the image inside the cell is covering it.

Answer (score 1):

Please take button in above of imageview with same size as cell. Just drag outlet and action of it. Use this code on button to manage selection and unselection.

Selection:

```
sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.35)
```

Unselection:

```
sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.0)
```

Happy Coding

Comment: I can't even see the default effect because the image inside the cell covers it. Or at least I believe that is what's happening. Would there be a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to slightly darken the cell and highlight it check the property in `UITaleView` that's called, `isUserInteractionEnabled`.

This behavior is already implemented by default in the `UITableViewCell`, however if that's not what you're looking for you can implement `didSelectRowAt` delegate function and do whatever you want on that cell, or you can use `didHighlightRowAt`.

You can read a lot about those functions online [here](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-multiple-selections-in-table-view-88dc2249c3a2) is an example about implementing the `didSelectRowAt`.

**UPDATE**: some work around to manually shows the user what he clicked, inside the `didSelectRowAt` method add implement this.

```
let cell =  (tableView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
   cell.imageView.highlightedImage = cell.imageView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
   cell.imageView.tintColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.3)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
                    talbeView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
})
}
```

This will manually cover the image inside the image view with the tint color you set in this case is black with opacity of `0.3`.

And then deselect the cell, all of this wrapped in a `0.4` animation time.

Comment: The default doesn't even show up for me because I think the image inside the cell is covering it somehow. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: make sure to add this line in `didLoad` and try again `tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled  = true `

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing changed. The table itself functions correctly.